# ImportError: No module named appengine.api

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just updated app engine and when I run dev_appserver . in my project directory I get the following error.

```
MacBook-xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx vinay$ dev_appserver.py .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 84, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 80, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import appinfo
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

---

UPDATE

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google
>>> print(google)
<module 'google' (built-in)>
```

Comment: What does `import google; print(google)` produce? You probably have a local file called `google.py` somewhere.

Comment: Hrm, that's not very helpful, that indicates a `google.so` file was loaded. Could be a problem with the released API I suppose.

Comment: @VinayJoseph...It would be helpful to the community here to post the answer to your question, that it is if you've already figured it out...Hopefully..:)

Comment: I have installed 1.9.37 today, OS X 10.11.4 and it works if I launch from the GoogleAppEngineLauncher. Have you updated the symlinks after the update? In the menu `GoogleAppEngineLauncher > Make Symlinks..."

Comment: Now also tried `dev_appserver.py` which prompts me to run `gcloud components update`. My current Cloud SDK version is 101.0.0 and it wants to install `gcloud app Python Extensions 1.9.34`. After confirmation it will launch the app as expected.

Comment: @VinayJoseph Whats the status ?

Answer (score 5):

My colleague had the same problem. He had an other google package installed, protobuf in his case.

If you try `print(google.__path__)`, it will probably say something else than the google appengine path. 
Or try `dir(google)` to get some idea of what is actually imported.

To solve this, he had to remove protobuf.